# Path to CSV is not working in DyGraph

Tags: javascript, csv, dygraphs

Below is my code in Javascript:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Dygraph</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.1/dygraph-combined.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graphdiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      g = new Dygraph(

        // containing div
        document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

        // CSV or path to a CSV file.
        "/home/khlim/Desktop/WeatherData/NewYork.csv", // path to CSV file
        {}          // options

      );
    </script>

</body>
```

I have a file named NewYork.csv and it is located in desktop in my linux machine. When I tried to run the script, nothing happens. Is there wrong with my code ?

Below is the format of NewYork.csv

```
DATE    TMAX
20150101    39
20150102    56
20150103    50
20150104    139
20150105    100
```

It contains 50,000 rows in total.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. Your "CSV" file doesn't contain comma-separated fields.
2. You're trying to load data from the local file system on a web page. This is not allowed because of security concerns.